PBI Service is giving refresh error while refresh is working fine on PBI desktop. I have mentioned the image with the exact error, unable to figure
Data source error:
DataSource.Error: OData: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
DataSourceKind = Dynamics365BusinessCentral. DataSourcePath = Dynamics365BusinessCentral. ;OData: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: Merge1.
Cluster URI:    WABI-US-NORTH-CENTRAL-J-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net

This is the exact refresh error that I am getting in Power BI Service.

I've ensured that the data source credentials are correct and have been re-entered in Power BI Service. The OData feed URL is properly configured in Power BI Desktop, and the data preview works without any issues. My internet connection is stable, and there are no network-related problems from my end. The dataset refreshes successfully in Power BI Desktop, but it consistently fails in Power BI Service. I've already attempted to increase timeout settings and reduce the data volume in the query to prevent any potential timeouts. Both Power BI Desktop and the On-Premises Data Gateway are up to date, yet the issue persists. Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.


Check out these things if any of them works--
Firewall or Network Restrictions not blocking Odata requests.
Use Incremental Refresh in Power BI if applicable. This is the best
way   to  reduce the data load and prevent timeouts.
Your cluster as mentioned (WABI-US-NORTH-CENTRAL-J-PRIMARY) is Azure
one.Please check once that the region is not down.
If you are using your company machine then please check If your
OData feed is protected by OAuth or not, verify if the OAuth token
is expiring during the  refresh.
At last Dynamics 365 Business Central has API limits and can
throttle or block requests ,if there are too many requests in a
short period. Might be possible that when Power BI Service
refreshes that may be hitting these limits and causing the
connection to be closed
    a)Check the API request limits on the Dynamics 365                                
       Business Central side and see if throttling is 
        occurring.
    b)Reduce the frequency of refreshes PBI



